# Как выставить список всех проектов в Android Studio, как в Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, java

Всем добрый вечер.
Наверняка тут абсолютно каждый работал в Eclipse, и было очень удобно, что все твои созданные проекты были слева в окошке, есть ли возможность так же выставить и в Android Studio? Если возможно, то как? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно открыть несколько проектов, каждый в своем окне. Списка проектов нет, т.к они загружаются с помощью gradle.